# Does Symfony DateTime validator support Y-m-dTH:i:s?

Tags: symfony, datetime, symfony-validator

I need to validate dates in Symfony and the expected format is Y-m-dTH:i:s, for example 2019-08-02T23:09:01

This is how the DateTime object is being instantiated:

```
//...some code
                    'start_date' => new DateTime([
                        'format' => 'Y-m-dTH:i:s'
                    ]),
//...some code
```

and even though start_date is correct (for example 2019-08-01T20:04:00), the validator still renders this invalid. If I try with 2019-08-01 20:04:00 and a format of 'Y-m-d H:i:s', then it works. Is it possible to use that T in the format?

Comment: Have you tried using format option for your validator?
https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/DateTime.html#format

Comment: Is the `T` literal designating the start of `time` part or timezone indicator? Because you might be looking for the `c` format:
https://implode.io/5m5qPK

Comment: @Domagoj yes, of course, I have tried that, as you can see in the question.

Comment: Have you tried escaping the `T` as `\T` or is it just a typo here?

Comment: in laravel also this is the solution: Y-m-d\TH:i:s

Comment: @danigore I've tried that before asking the question, nu luck, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Whats the  origin of  the date  that you want to validate ?  It's from form(user input?)  ?

**If yes**

then  you should use DateTime Assert on entity connected to form 
https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/DateTime.html

also

you can use datetime field (https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/datetime.html)  on form to validate on data input

**If no**

If you have value from (for example)  database, and you are not sure if is it  vaild 
you can use Datetime Assert ( link  above) with  validating  "raw values"  , here is  example :
https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/raw_values.html